# JavaScript IIFE functions and variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables, iife

Reading *JavaScript Puzzlers!*, I was following up until I came across this kind of situation.

The code

```js
var name = "abc";
(function () {
    console.log(name);
    var name = "xyz";
    console.log(name);
}) ();
```

returns

```
undefined
xyz
```

But this one

```js
var name = "abc";
(function () {
    console.log(name);
}) ();
```

returns

```
abc
```

I am confused, why is `name` undefined is the first code on the first call? I guess this is because of JavaScript hoisting and other reasons. In what do these two pieces of code differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), this is just [*var hoisting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) as you guessed. You would have the same situation with a classic function.

The fact that you redeclared `name` **somewhere** in the IIFE cancels the global scope of `name` within this IIFE. The first time you call `name` within your IIFE, it behaves as if it was declared (without initialization) at the top of the current scope (the IIFE here) and is thus `undefined`.

You can test the *var hoisting* concept with this little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jd94m37w/) by commenting and uncommenting a line.

Comment: so that's it, thanks, i didn't notice there is a name in the IIFE, :dizzy: